# SIGINT caught only one time

Tags: c, signals, posix, system-calls

Given this code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sigint_handler(int h)
{
    printf("Hey! I caught a SIGINT! :)\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = &sigint_handler;

    if (0 != sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL)) {
        perror("unable to setup the SIGINT handler!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    while(1) { }

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc 7.2.0` (kernel `4.13.12`) using the following options: `-Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=gnu11`.

The first signal is always caught, but sometimes, the second one is not caught, and sometimes it is.

I encountered this bug while spamming `Ctrl-C` at process' startup.

What did I miss to catch all signals?

Comment: Your SIGINT handler has only one line - a call to a function that is not async-signal safe:(

Comment: @MartinJames Thank you for your help! It's quickly explained in `signal-safety(7)`.

Comment: You've no idea what the other fields in the `struct sigaction` are set to because you didn't initialize `act`. Maybe you will get better behaviour if you set the documented fields to know values.  You can use `write()` in a POSIX signal handler (not in standard C, but fortunately you're not using standard C).  You shouldn't use `printf()`, though in this context it is unlikely to cause any trouble.  One minor advantage of `write()` — there's no application level buffering to worry about.

Comment: Is your problem resolved?  If so, maybe you should delete this question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your help. I prefer to post an answer based on the problems you've pointed instead of deleting my question, with the hope that it will help someone later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Martin James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james) observed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070017/sigint-caught-only-one-time?noredirect=1#comment83113909_48070017):

> Your SIGINT handler has only one line - a call to a function that is not async-signal safe:(

Somewhat later, I [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070017/sigint-caught-only-one-time?noredirect=1#comment83118187_48070017):

> You've no idea what the other fields in the `struct sigaction` are set to because you didn't initialize `act`. Maybe you will get better behaviour if you set the documented fields to known values. You can use `write()` in a POSIX signal handler (not in standard C, but fortunately you're not using standard C). You shouldn't use `printf()`, though in this context it is unlikely to cause any trouble. One minor advantage of `write()` — there's no application level buffering to worry about.

The question [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/) discusses which functions can be used in a signal handler. <s>Note that the functions from the `<string.h>` header such as `strlen()` and `strchr()` are not listed amongst those that are async-signal safe.  I find that omission puzzling, but that's what POSIX (2008 and earlier) says.</s> (This was accurate for POSIX 2008.  One of the changes in POSIX 2016 is that a number of signal-safe routines have been added to the list in [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), including both `strlen()` and `strchr()` — this makes a lot of sense to me.)

I adapted your code like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sigint_handler(int h)
{
    char message[] = "Hey! I caught a SIGINT x! :\n";
    char *x = message;
    while (*x != 'x' && *x != '\0')
        x++;
    if (*x != '\0')
        *x = (h % 10) + '0';
    write(1, message, sizeof(message) - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act = { 0 };
    act.sa_handler = &sigint_handler;

    if (0 != sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL))
    {
        perror("Unable to setup the SIGINT handler!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Pausing for a moment...\n");
        pause();
        printf("You interrupted my dozing\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code uses [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) rather than spinning in a busy-loop.  It's an unusual system call; it never returns normally (the `exec*()` family of functions never return normally either).

I compile with stringent warning options:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes sig13.c -o sig13
$
```

If I didn't use `h` (the argument to the signal handler), the code wouldn't compile, so I used it.  The code avoids using string handling functions (`char *x = strchr(message, 'x'); if (x != 0) *x = (h % 10) + '0';` would be clearer).  The function is `static` because it won't be used outside this file — so there isn't a header to declare it.

When executed (on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, using GCC 7.2.0), it produces output like:

```
$ ./sig13
Pausing for a moment...
^CHey! I caught a SIGINT 2! :
You interrupted my dozing
Pausing for a moment...
^CHey! I caught a SIGINT 2! :
You interrupted my dozing
Pausing for a moment...
^CHey! I caught a SIGINT 2! :
You interrupted my dozing
Pausing for a moment...
^CHey! I caught a SIGINT 2! :
You interrupted my dozing
Pausing for a moment...
^CHey! I caught a SIGINT 2! :
You interrupted my dozing
Pausing for a moment...
^\Quit: 3
$
```

The main moral to this is "make sure your variables are properly initialized".  A secondary moral is to make sure your signal handler is clean.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. BTW, in `signal-safety(7)`, both `strlen` and `strchr` are listed as *async-signal-safe* with the mention: *"Added in POSIX.1-2016"*.

Comment: Hmmm; you're right.  I hadn't gone back to look at the list recently, as you can tell.  I have some updating to do.  Thank you!  (And thank you POSIX for putting some sanity into the list of signal safe functions.)

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems with my code, first of all, as mentionned by @MartinJames and @j31d0, the `printf` function is not [async-signal-safe](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), so it can't be used inside the signal handler. It can be easily replaced by the `write` system-call which is async-signal-safe:

```
char message[255] = "Hey! I caught a SIGINT :)\n";
write(1, message, 255);
```

Secondly, the variable `act` was not properly initialized (as mentionned by @JonathanLeffler):

```
sigset_t mask;
struct sigaction act;

sigemptyset(&mask);
act.sa_handler = &sigint_handler;
act.sa_mask = mask;
act.sa_flags = 0;
```

Finally, a working code would then be the following:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sigint_handler(int h)
{
    char message[255] = "Hey! I caught a SIGINT :)\n";
    write(1, message, 255);
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t mask;
    struct sigaction act;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    act.sa_handler = &sigint_handler;
    act.sa_mask = mask;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (0 != sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL)) {
        perror("unable to setup the SIGINT handler!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    while(1) { }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!